# Passing parameters to a Visualforce email template within Apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, scheduled-apex

I am working on setting up a scheduled apex class to send out emails to me every day.  I have a visualforce template that takes a user and an opportunity as parameters that I would like to use.  The scheduler works great and an email gets sent but the message body is blank.  Here is my code that builds the email.  Is there something I am doing wrong?  I have tested the visualforce template by sending it to myself through the salesforce UI and it works fine.

```
          public static void mail60(Opportunity op)
{

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    string [] toaddress= New string[]{'my email address'};
    email.settemplateid(' template ID here'); //In the real code I have the correct IDs in place
    email.setSubject( 'Blah - Maintenance and Support Renewal');
    email.setToAddresses(toaddress);
    email.setTargetObjectId(' contact ID here '); //In the real code I have the correct IDs in place
    email.setWhatId(' opportunity ID here '); //In the real code I have the correct IDs in place
    email.saveAsActivity = false;
    Messaging.sendEmail(New Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});

}
```

Comment: You should include the code for the email, the template markup & any controllers associated with it. You said it yourself, the email sends & arrives fine, but the body is blank, so its probably not an issue with your sending code, but your email template.

Comment: I have tested the email template with the 'Send Test and Verify Merge Fields' button and I have tried sending it to myself (I added myself as a contact in Salesforce) from the Salesforce UI and it works in both cases.  The controller and visualforce component are lengthy, if you need to see them still I will post it.

Comment: Maybe a reduced version which still behaves the same? Removing all of the markup except for a field value or two for testing?

Comment: Oen nitpick with your post - you say you have a template which takes a user and a opportunity, but you provide a contact id for the targetobjectId? Do you provide a user id when testing through the UI, or a contact Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things wrong,

1. when using template you dont have to set subject.
2. When you use setTargetObjectId, your email is sent to that contact/lead or user. You dont have to set toAddress

Instead of such complex code, you can do it

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = 
            Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, whoId, whatId);
```

So your code will be like

```
public static void mail60(Opportunity op){

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = 
                Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate('templateId', ' contact ID here ', op.Id);

    string [] ccAddress= new string[]{'my email address'};
    email.setccAddresses(ccAddress);
    email.saveAsActivity = false;
    Messaging.sendEmail(New Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});

}
```

SRC: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm

SRC:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm

Comment: Made my code simpler and made it work.  Thank you!